# Threading.Thread and Threading.Task on same application , does tasks taking considerations of that?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

i'm developing application with few thread (each is working on it's queue) and with parallel tasks (Parallel.For or just Thread.StartNew).

my question is if MS threading components that was introduced in last versions of threading (like threadpool, tasks,...) are aware of other threads i have manually defined when they execute an operation on a new thread.

for example: if i have pc with 4 cpu's and 1 thread that works on a queue (the thread not always working, it uses reset events etc) and i have 10 concurrent actions that runs (each) on it's task. does it means that 3 tasks will run with my application while the other tasks wait for them (the tasks) to finish? what will happen when the thread go to sleep (do the task operation will run on the cpu that the thread was on? and if it does, what will happen when my thread need to run immidiatly and the task that took the cpu time hangs it? does it mean that my thread wont run also, or in some point i'll see context switch?)

lot's and lot's of questions... hope someone will be patient and have me an answer :)

Thanks,
Tzahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ThreadPool/TPL infrastructure has no clue about the "manually" created threads, it will just do its best to tune itself to use the CPU resources available. From there you are relying on the operating system to do its job and schedule the threads around each other. For example, if your manual thread is blocked waiting on an object, it won't consume resources and the OS will schedule another available thread (maybe from the ThreadPool/TPL) to execute instead. If you think about it, this is really no different than multiple applications running on the OS. They know nothing about each other, yet the OS does its best to keep everyone happy and getting their fare share of the resources that are available.